# Make rtl Design of Fragment

Tags: android, xml, right-to-left

I have a problem in my fragment design.Layout's component are `rtl` and desirable in the android studio environment.But when I run my application on my device,they become `ltr`. I put my `xml` code and Two image of design.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   tools:context=".Fragment.ProfileFragment"
  >
 <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <include
        layout="@layout/profile_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp">

    </include>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgEditName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="مریم"
                android:textColor="#433D3E" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="نام "
                android:textColor="#D0CFCF" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgEditFamily"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtFamily"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="کاظمی"
                android:textColor="#433D3E" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleFamily"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="نام خانوادگی"
                android:textColor="#D0CFCF" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgEditMail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtMail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="example@gmail.com"
                android:textColor="#433D3E" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleMail"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="ایمیل"
                android:textColor="#D0CFCF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgEditPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtPhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="09337852463"
                android:textColor="#433D3E" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitlePhone"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="شماره تلفن همراه : "
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="شماره تلفن"
                android:textColor="#D0CFCF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imgEditUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_edit" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:text="SampleUser"
                android:textColor="#433D3E" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleUserName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:hint="نام کاربری : "
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="نام کاربری"
                android:textColor="#D0CFCF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnAddress"
                style="@style/StyleButton"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:text="مشاهده آدرس ها" />


            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/txtTitleAddress"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.5"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:paddingRight="10dp"
                android:text="آدرس ها"
                android:textColor="#D0CFCF" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnChangePassword"
                style="@style/StyleButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="تغییر رمز عبور" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSaveProfile"
            style="@style/StyleButton"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:text="ذخیره تغییرات">
        </Button>
         </LinearLayout>
     </LinearLayout>
 </FrameLayout>
```

[image: Showed design in my device]
[image: Design in android studio]

Answer (score 0):

the attribute `android:layoutDirection` in `LinearLayout` default is ltr in android studio, but in real device attribiute set by direction of your mobile language.
set `android:layoutDirection="ltr"` in `LinearLayout`